# Make Webpack 1.13 work with ES6 vendor

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to add some external dependency `cryptowatch-embed` js to my webpack project (of version 1.13.3) as vendor. The concern is that this dependency is written in ES6 style and js file ends with something like `export default Embed;`. When I run my `webpack-dev-server` and open the browser the console shows me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` on this line. I suppose that webpack does not bundle ES6 vendor properly, but I dot'n have any ideas what should be done to fix this error. So the main question is how can I make webpack work with `/node_modules/cryptowatch-embed/src/main.js` that is written in ES6?

Comment: You can use https://babeljs.io/ http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-data/babel-webpack/

Comment: How can I apply babel loader only for this dependency? @anttud